# What is the blue candle buff/de buff?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When exploring the dungeon I saw a buff or de buff pop up on screen. What is the buff? What does it do? Would it be a good idea to put the candle in my home?

Answer (score 1):

That blue candle you're seeing is a [Water Candle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Candle). When you're within range of it, it increases the spawn rate by 30%, and the maximum number of enemies on screen by 50%, so unless you're planning on farming enemies near your house, it probably wouldn't be a good idea to put the candle there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a water candle: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Water_Candle

It causes monsters to spawn 33% faster and also allows 50% more enemies on the screen simultaneously.

Holding a candle near a placed candle stacks the effect.